# Mongoose: 'Cast to embedded failed for value at path. Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id'

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm having some trouble trying to save an array inside an array of objects.

I'm getting the following response from the server:

```
{ [CastError: Cast to embedded failed for value "\'maxbeds: 4\'" at  path "saved_searches"]
message: 'Cast to embedded failed for value "\\\'maxbeds: 4\\\'" at path "saved_searches"',
name: 'CastError',
kind: 'embedded',
value: '\'maxbeds: 4\'',
path: 'saved_searches',
reason: [TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in maxbeds: 4] }
```

Here's my Schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
rfr = require('rfr'),
passwordHelper = rfr('server/helpers/password.js'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema,
_ = require('lodash');

/*
* 
* Creating UserSchema for MongoDB
*
*/

var UserSchema = new Schema({
 email: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
  unique: true
},
password: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
  select: false
},
name: {
  type: String,
  required: true
},
passwordSalt: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
  select: false
},
saved_houses: [{
  mlsId: {
    type: String
  },
  addressFull: {
    type: String
  },
  bedrooms: {
    type: Number
  },
  listPrice: {
    type: Number
  },
  bathrooms: {
    type: Number
  },
  sqft: {
    type: Number
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
}],
saved_searches: [{
  search_name: {
    type: String
  },
  filters: {
    type: [Schema.Types.Mixed]
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
}],
active: {
  type: Boolean,
  default: true
},
createdAt: {
  type: Date,
  default: Date.now
}
});
// compile User model
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

The problem, I believe is the filters array that live inside an object inside the saved_searches array

Now, in my router I do the following:

```
var express = require('express'),
savedDataRouter = express.Router(),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
rfr = require('rfr'),
s = rfr('server/routes/config/jwt_config.js'),
User = rfr('server/models/User.js'),
jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

savedDataRouter.post('/searches', function (req, res) {
  if (mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.body.userId)) {
      User.findByIdAndUpdate({
              _id: req.body.userId
          }, {
              $push: {
                  saved_searches: {
                      search_name: req.body.search_name,
                      $each: req.body.filters
                  }
              },
          }, {
              new: true
          },
          function (err, doc) {
              if (err || !doc) {
                  console.log(err);
                  res.json({
                      status: 400,
                      message: "Unable to save search." + err

                  });
              } else {
                  return res.json(doc);
              }
          });
  } else {
      return res.status(404).json({
          message: "Unable to find user"
      });
  }
});
```

If I log the request body coming from the client I get the following:

```
//console.log(req.body)
{ search_name: 'Sarasota',
filters: [ 'minbaths: 1', 'maxbaths: 3', 'minbeds: 2', 'maxbeds: 4' ],
userId: '583359409a1e0167d1a3a2b3' }
```

I've tried all the things I've seen in Stack Overflow and other online resources with no luck. What am I doing wrong?

### Edit

Added module dependencies to my UserSchema and SavedDataRouter

Comment: can you elaborate on what are you trying to achieve. what should be the correct saved_search object(s) ?

Comment: @Gurbakhshish Singh well Im basically trying to pass 2 arguments: search_name which is a string and filters which is an array of strings. What I'm trying to do is have my database look for the correct user and embed this information in an array of objects called saved_searches. That way a successful post would look like saved_searches:{search_name:'some string', filters: [array_of_strings]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate({
          _id: req.body.userId
      }, {
          $push: {
              saved_searches: {
                  search_name: req.body.search_name,
                  filters: req.body.filters
              }
          },
      }, {
          new: true
      },
      function (err, doc) {
          if (err || !doc) {
              console.log(err);
              res.json({
                  status: 400,
                  message: "Unable to save search." + err

              });
          } else {
              return res.json(doc);
          }
      });
```

Comment: It makes a lot more sense. I feel stupid for forgetting to reference the field im sending the filers. However, I'm getting a different error now =   "The dollar ($) prefixed field \'$each\' in \'saved_searches..filters.0.$each\' is not valid for storage/", Im researching what it could be.

Comment: That was it! Thanks! Now I'm starting to understand how arrays work in mongo.